# Подскажите, как сделан эффект параллакса

Tags: jquery, html, css

Мне нужен такой же сайт, конечно с другим дизайном, но не могу понять, как создаются такие параллакс сайты. Могу сказать, что на ширину и высоту ставится 100%, а остальное скрывается overflow:hidden. Ссылки крепятся якорем, я так понимаю. Пожалуйста будьте добры, подскажите. Вот пример [сайта](http://www.farmhousefare.co.uk)

Comment: https://github.com/404

Answer (score 1):

Это просто подшамененный плагин на jquery:

https://github.com/IanLunn
http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm
http://habrahabr.ru/post/142137/
http://stephband.info/jparallax/

Можно так же просто скопировать код того сайта и подправить под себя